# I would like to save object that selected it save correctly and return object in json but can not bind returned object

Tags: angular, types

i have select it work correctly in add but in edit it can not bind selected vlue 
`and this is a pic to explain my problem[enter image description here][1]`

```
 getPages() {
  this.pagesService.getPages(this.projectId).subscribe((data: any  ) => {
    this.pages = data.result ;
    this.pages = this.pages.map(page => new PageModel(page.id, page.name,
      page.url, page.elements) );
    console.log('pages');
    console.log( this.pages);
  });
```

}

I would like to save object that selected it save correctly and return object in json but can not bind returned object.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproduction of this in stackblitz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 getPages() {
      this.pagesService.getPages(this.projectId).subscribe((data: any  ) => {
        this.pages = data.result ;
        let _pages = this.pages.map(page => new PageModel(page.id, page.name,
          page.url, page.elements) );
        this.pages = _pages;
        console.log('pages');
        console.log( this.pages);
      });
```

In the error, it is clearly said that, you cannot update it while you are editing

Comment: Yes I chaned  it as you said but it still not binding in edit mode

Comment: may be error in this            getElements(pageId) {
this.selectedValue = pageId;
  const selectedPage = this.pages.filter(page => {
    return page.pageid.includes(pageId);
  });
    if (selectedPage) {
      this.data.page = selectedPage[0];
      const elements = selectedPage[0].elements.map(element => new Element(element.id,
        element.elementName, element.identifierType, element.identifierValue
      ) );
      this.elements = elements;
    }
        console.log('elements');
     console.log(this.elements);
  }

Comment: Yeah, the problem lacks enough information to reproduce. I have tried the above code and it perfectly works

Comment: ok   this is my whole code   i get all pages and get elements in every page using getElements(pageId) {
this.selectedValue = pageId;
  const selectedPage = this.pages.filter(page => {
    return page.pageid.includes(pageId);
  });
    if (selectedPage) {
      const page = selectedPage[0];
      this.elements = page .elements;
      this.data.page = page;
    }
        console.log('elements');
     console.log(this.elements);
  }

Comment: ang to get element on event change fir i used  onChange(value) {
    const selectedElement = this.elements.filter(element => {
      return element.elementId.includes(value.elementId);
      });
      this.data.element = selectedElement[0];
    this.getSteps.emit(this.data);
      }

Comment: I dont see you have included your code in there. Did you save it on stackblitz? Ctrl + S

Comment: When you replace your code with mine, what happened?

Comment: pages worked correctly but problem still in elements